# Drag and drop marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, drag-and-drop

i want to create marker on google map through dragging marker image from outside the map canvas and drop it inside the canvas, i've registered dom event listener of google maps but inside the listener i have no access to latLng object, how do i find the latLng of dropping point?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Active Users</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=maps&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="big_wrapper">
        <div id="gmap_canvas" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <div id="controls">
           <div class="command">
              Coordinates: <br />
              <input type="text" id="lat" value="33.718629" /><br />

              <input type="text" id="lng" value="73.059082" /><br />
              <input type="button" value="Go" id="go" />
           </div>

           <div class="command">
               Markers: <br />
               <img src="img/marker.png" id="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
           </div>
           <div class="command" id="debug">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
var geocoder;
var map;

$(function() {

    $("#go").click(function()
    {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($("#lat").val(), $("#lng").val()));
    });


});

function initialize() {
    // prepare Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.718629,73.059082);

    var myOptions = { // default map options
        zoom: 2,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    mapDiv = document.getElementById('gmap_canvas');

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(event)
    {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = map.getCenter().lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = map.getCenter().lng();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e)
    {
        alert(e.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'drop', function(event)
    {
        alert(event);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click');
    });
}

function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    alert(ev.latLng);
}

// initialization
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solve this problem by creating an empty [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#OverlayView) to have access to the [MapCanvasProjection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(Point)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#MapCanvasProjection) function.

Here is a piece of code you can just add in yours :

```
/**
 * initialize a empty overlay used to compute latlng from pixel
 */
function initOverlay() {
    function DropOverlay(map) {
        this.setMap(map);
    }
    DropOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    DropOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function()    { /* Nothing to add */    };
    DropOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() { /* Nothing to remove */ };
    DropOverlay.prototype.draw = function()     { /* Nothing to draw */   };
    DropOverlay.prototype.fromPixelToLatLng = function(x, y) {
        var offset = divOffset(map.getDiv());
        return this.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(x - offset.x, y - offset.y));
    } 
    return new DropOverlay(map);
}


/** 
 * compute absolute position on page of a DOM element
 */
function divOffset(div) {
    var offset = {x:0, y:0};
    do {
        offset.x += div.offsetLeft;
        offset.y += div.offsetTop;
    } while(div = div.offsetParent);

    return offset;
}
```

Then you can call var overlay = initOverlay() in your in initialize() function. And use overlay.fromPixelToLatLng() to get le LatLng in your drop() function.

I hope this will help you. Or someone else landing on this page.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Saved a whole lot of heartache